# Site with inifinite scroll suddenly reloads with error message in Safari on an iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, mobile-safari

Working on a site and got feedback from the client that when browsing the site on an iPad and iPad Mini the site will suddenly reload with the message "A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded".

The site it's happening on is a fairly image heavy one, it's infinite scroll page with about 60 entries, retina enhanced imagery via `<picture>` element.

Never seen this before, what's causing it, and how can I get around it?
Perhaps it runs out ouf memory? But I thought iOS was smart enough to dump images out of view if it needs memory to load new stuff?

Apparently this did not happen on iPhones (I take it they tried with 5S and 6), but that's probably because the total screen resolution is much lesser and the images are smaller in file size..

Answer (score 2):

The only way to find out is to plug an iPad/iPad Mini into a Mac running Safari and inspect the page runing on the device. So, first, turn on the "Develop" menu (in OS X Safari's Advanced Preferences), like this:
[image: Turn on Safari Develop menu]

Then from the `Develop` menu you can select the device you want to inspect Mobile Safari on… like this:
[image]

That gives you effectively the same inspector that the desktop version of Safari uses and hopefully you'll find some clues as to what is going wrong. (I'm betting Javascript error).

Comment: Nice, did not know this. Gonna update iOS Simulator aswell and see if it happens there. This seems to be connected to 8.0.2 = https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6563053